# Keycloak - Spring Boot: I/O Error on GET request for "https://myhostname/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration"

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, traefik

I have setup keycloak in docker like follows:

```
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.1
    container_name: keycloak
    command:
      - start-dev
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`myhostname.com`) && PathPrefix(`/auth`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt'
    environment:
      KC_DB: mariadb
      KC_DB_URL: ${KC_DB_URL}
      KC_DB_USERNAME: ${MARIADB_USERNAME}
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: ${KEYCLOAK_SUPER_ADMIN_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_SUPER_ADMIN_PASS}
      KC_PROXY: ${KC_PROXY:-passthrough}
      KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH: ${KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH:-/auth}
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/docker/keycloak:/opt/keycloak/data/import
    ports:
      - ${KEYCLOAK_PORT:-8087}:8080
    depends_on:
      - db-keycloak
    networks:
      net:
```

As you can see I expose it to path /auth with traefik. I've also setup on the same host a spring boot application like this:

```
  app:
    container_name: app
    image: ghcr.io/repo/image:tag
    environment:
      MARIADB_HOST: ${MARIADB_HOST}
      MARIADB_PORT: ${MARIADB_PORT}
      MARIADB_DATABASE: ${MARIADB_DATABASE}
      MARIADB_USERNAME: ${MARIADB_USERNAME}
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_PASSWORD}
      KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID}
      KC_HOSTNAME_URL: ${KC_HOSTNAME_URL}
      KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME: ${KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME}
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:8080
    restart: always
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`myhostname.com`) && PathPrefix(`/app`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.app.entrypoints=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.app.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.app.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt'
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - net
```

The spring boot application is also expose via traefik on path /app. When the spring boot application starts and tries to connect with keycloak I get the following error:

`Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://myhostname.com/auth/realms/realm/.well-known/openid-configuration": Connection refused`

Here is the `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID}
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: ${KC_HOSTNAME_URL}/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME}
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ${KC_HOSTNAME_URL}/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME}
```

And the `SecurityConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {
  public static final String USER = "user";
  private final KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;

  SecurityConfig(KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler) {
    this.keycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler;
  }

  @Bean
  protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
      .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.oauth2Login()
      .and()
      .logout()
      .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
      .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

I've tried setting `Web Origins: *` but it did not work.
I've also tried setting the KC_HOSTNAME_URL variable to `http://keycloak:8080/auth` which does connect to keycloak but then the authorization doesn't work.

Comment: Suggestion go to Realm Settings -> Endpoints -> click on  OpenID Endpoint Configuration, you can see in json format open id configuration for your current realm.  like this: "token_endpoint": "http://your_hostname.com/realms/your_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token"